# What are the similarities and differences between Amazon's business model and China's approach to managing its tech businesses?

Tags: economy, china, technology, capitalism

#### Background:

CNN's [Jamie Dimon says he regrets joking about the Chinese Communist Party](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/11/24/business/jamie-dimon-jpmorgan-china-joke-intl-hnk/index.html) says of JPMorgan (JPM) CEO Jamie Dimon:

> At one point, Dimon compared the political and economic approaches in both countries, saying that in the United States, "we have the gifts of our founding fathers: freedom of speech, freedom of religion, freedom of enterprise, freedom of human capital, immigration."
>
> "If you opened up the doors of America, a billion people would come here. If you open the doors to China, how many people do you think will go there?" he said.
>
> "**[An] autocratic ... economy doesn't work particularly well as a country gets much more sophisticated.** And I'm not saying this to be angry to China. I think they have done a better job managing that country than we would have done at managing that country. They are very smart."

(Emphasis mine)

China of course has managed to produce a(n until at least recently) flourishing tech business sector, due in no small part to having a huge and newly tech-hungry customer base within China, a [great firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) around it, and a limited period of time when it was allowed to grow "free market"-style.

These days the central government is reigning in various large sectors of the economy with new regulation and central control, with one of the most notable being the temporary [disappearance of Jack Ma and sudden cancellation of the Ant Group's IPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Ma#Disappearance_from_the_public_eye), and [In its latest crackdown, China intensifies focus on real estate](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2021/7/28/in-its-latest-crackdown-china-intensifies-focus-on-real-estate).

#### Question:

- The Wall Street Journal [Amazon Scooped Up Data From Its Own Sellers to Launch Competing Products](https://www.wsj.com/articles/amazon-scooped-up-data-from-its-own-sellers-to-launch-competing-products-11587650015)
- Business Insider [House antitrust report accuses Amazon of using third-party seller data to copy popular products — something the tech giant has repeatedly denied](https://www.businessinsider.com/amazon-uses-seller-data-copy-products-alleges-house-antitrust-report-2020-10)
- US House Subcommittee on Antitrust, Commercial and Administrative Law of the Committee on the Judiciary [Investigation of Competition in Digital Markets; Majority Staff Report and Recommendations](https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/editorialfiles/2020/10/06/investigation_of_competition_in_digital_markets_majority_staff_report_and_recommendations.pdf)

Many sellers on Amazon have complained that Amazon's business model includes providing an environment for free competition up to the point that something looks successful, and then "taking over" by selling their own very similar product based on access to the other seller's information.

The title suggest that China may borrow from this playbook, but differently in that after high tech businesses have become successful through an artificial, temporary free market environment it simply grabs control, leaving the companies in place but now under new, sudden and very substantial central government control.

**Question:** Did China "borrow" from Amazon's playbook? Is this a reasonable analogy or is it substantially flawed? If so, is there a more accurate one?

**NOTE:** By definition A can only be an analogy of B if it *is not the same thing as B*. It must have substantial differences to be analogous, otherwise it's simply the same thing. So a "No" answer can't simply be "It's not the same thing", it must go farther.

Comment: Why would anyone consider Dimon's statement a joke?  Seems like a basically accurate observation.

Comment: I think sometimes when folks can't think of an answer that's fact based they figure nobody else could either, so vtc as "opinion-based" rather than allow someone to post a fact based answer.

Comment: @jamesqf: freedom is relative. A lot of North Koreans would probably go to China if they could. Insofar there hasn't really been a case where people could easily go to a non-free but richer (e.g. GDP/capita) country. When/it that becomes a common possibility it would be interesting to see what people would choose indeed.

Comment: @Fizz: Can't disagree with that, but it doesn't answer my question - which I admit is tanental to the OP's question: why do people say that Dimon was joking?

Comment: @jamesqf I assume those people are taking is word at face value; the title of the CNN article for example is "Jamie Dimon says he regrets joking about the Chinese Communist Party". Others may take a more nuanced approach and assume that while he was being humorous in his delivery he believed every word he said and is using the term "joking" as a way to reduce tension without actually reversing position. At least that's my understanding of how people perceive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are some similarities between government regulatory power and in how a "market platform monopoly" can tell its sellers what to do (and that extends beyond Amazon to things like Apple and [to a slightly lesser extent] Google stores), I don't really see how China imitates those factors specific to the Amazon copying/generics model, which--by the way--is nothing terribly new, having [been done](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/50069/29579) by brick-and-mortal supermarkets before.

What China has done is somewhat different (from Amazon), in that it has practically excluded a good number of foreign companies from its domestic market, typically by regulations that foreign companies have found hard to comply with. Surely, the Chinese government is happier to have China-based companies for both control- but also (local) know-how reasons. This is also something not so new, as ["national champions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_champions) have been promoted elsewhere.

One could mention here that the Chinese companies have themselves
exhibited monopolistic behavior that have even worried the Chinese
regulators. E.g. the on-line payment companies [forcing](https://verfassungsblog.de/alibaba/) their customers
not to use their [Chinese] competitors, aka  ‘choose one from two’.

When one speaks of "national champions" in China, it's somewhat
different in tech sectors than in traditional state-owned enterprise ones.
Because of China's very hands-off approach to local monopolies until this year,
a lot of foreign money [went](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/09/24/new-china-investment-paradigm-after-beijings-after-school-crackdown.html) into betting on which Chinese company will muscle out
their competitors in any given domain, including areas that are entirely domestic,
like tutoring companies.

Slightly of an aside, but China has now [issued guidance](https://www.dw.com/en/china-eyes-germanys-famous-hidden-champions-model/a-58986878) to develop "little giant" enterprises, which are seen as an attempt to copy Germany's "hidden champions"--companies that dominate or are among the market leaders in narrow/obscure niches.